# How to solve the correlationID message for Azure Bot Service?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to edit setting for my bot. But each time i click on save we receive this message:

"CorrelationID: |OZBV5.4b38250_"
"CorrelationID: |uytKo.4b3c387_"

and nothing has been saved.

Comment: Please report this issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder/issues/new & include your bot's app ID and Azure Bot Service ID.